# OkHttp interceptor doesn't get called from Observable

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, observable, okhttp

I am trying to write unit tests for my RX Observable calls in Android.  I am setting up my Retrofit RestAdapter like this:

```
        RestAdapter.Builder restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder();
        restAdapter
                .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(getGson()))
                .setClient(new OkClient(getHttpClient()));
```

And I'm passing it an OkHttpClient like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new AuthenticationInterceptor());
```

However, none of my Observable calls are getting intercepted.  In fact, it seems that the network calls don't fire up AT ALL.  Anybody experience a similar issue?

EDIT:
Here is how I am calling the Observable from my unit test

```
TestSubscriber<User> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    mLoginUtils.doEmailLogin("customer", new AuthCredentials("test@mail.com", "testpassword")).subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

Comment: Same error when using Retrofit 1.8, but it works well when using retrofit 1.9+

Answer (score 4):

You need to subscribe to the Observable, otherwise it will not be fired up.

Apparently Retrofit implements it as "cold observables".

From the [ReactiveX docs](http://%E2%80%9CHot%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9CCold%E2%80%9D%20Observables)

> A “cold” Observable, on the other hand, waits until an observer
>   subscribes to it before it begins to emit items, and so such an
>   observer is guaranteed to see the whole sequence from the beginning.

Comment: I am subscribing like this:         `doEmailLogin("customer", new AuthCredentials("test@mail.com", "testpassword")).subscribe(testSubscriber);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your OkHttp interceptor is not getting called. I've always used Retrofit request interceptors. If you are just trying to add an authentication header that will work for you. Here's an example based on code that has worked for me:

```
// Create the OkHttp client        
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
SSLContext sslContext;
try {
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(); // The system has no TLS. Just give up.
}
Client client = okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

// Create the Retrofit RestAdapter
RestAdapter.LogLevel logLevel = BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE;
return new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.API_URL)
        .setClient(client)
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(getGson()))
        .setRequestInterceptor(new RetrofitAuthenticationInterceptor())
        .setLogLevel(logLevel)
        .build()
        .create(ApiServiceV1.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main issue is that my network calls are not going through on my unit tests (jvm based).  That's why I was concerned about the Request Interceptor not firing off - as that evidenced my symptom.